# How to templatize code for a class member function based on constructor parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have a highly performance-sensitive (read low latency requirement) C++ 17 class for logging that has member functions that can either log locally or can log remotely depending upon the flags with which the class is implemented. "Remote Logging" or "Local Logging" functionality is fully defined at the time when the object is constructed.

The code looks something like this

```
class Logger {
public:
    Logger(bool aIsTx):isTx_(aIsTx) {init();}
    ~Logger() {}

    uint16_t fbLog(const fileId_t aId, const void *aData, const uint16_t aSz){
        if (isTx_) 
                      // do remote logging
                      return remoteLog(aId, aData, aSz);
        else 
                      // do local logging
                      return fwrite(aData, aSz, 1,fd_[aId]);
    }
protected:
bool isTx_
}
```

What I would like to do is

- Some way of removing the `if(isTx_)` such that the code to be used gets defined at the time of instantiating.
- Since the class objects are used by multiple other modules, I would not like to templatize the class because this will require me to wrap two templatized implementations of the class in an interface wrapper which will result in v-table call every time a member function is called.

Comment: Either the class writes onto disk, or sends across network? A mere branch or virtual function call is unlikely to have measurable impact on performance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "templetize" the behaviour, since you want the choice to be done at runtime.

In case you want to get rid of the `if` because of performance, rest assured that it will have negligible impact compared to disk access or network communication. Same goes for virtual function call.

If you need low latency, I recommend considering asynchronous logging: The main thread would simply copy the message into an internal buffer. Memory is way faster than disk or network, so there will be much less latency. You can then have a separate service thread that waits for the buffer to receive messages, and handles the slow communication.

As a bonus, you don't need branches or virtual functions in the main thread since it is the service thread that decides what to do with the messages.

Asynchronisity is not an easy approach however. There are many cases that must be taken into consideration:

- How to synchronise the access to the buffer (I suggest trying out a lock free queue instead).
- How much memory should the buffer be allowed to occupy? Without limit it can consume too much if the program logs faster than can be written.
- If the buffer limit is reached, what should the main thread do? It either needs to fall back to synchronously waiting while the buffer is being processed or messages need to be discarded.
- How to flush the buffer when the program crashes? If it is not possible, then the last messages may be lost - which probably are what you need to figure out why the program crashed in the first place.

Regardless of choice: If performance is critical, then try out multiple approaches and measure.

Comment: There is a requirement for having both kind (local/remote) of logging depending upon the mode the application is running. In fact, in remote log mode we are simply passing the logging to another process via IPC. However, I might agree with you that not much juice can be extracted by avoiding the branch and hence trying to avoid occassional bubbles in pipeline. Thanks anyway.